# Code returning constant value

Tags: matlab

```
r = 0.4;
a = 0:0.1:10; 
t = r*cosd(a); 
x = 1 - r*sind(a); 
n = (t/x); 
plot(a,t,'--');
```

Value of n is returning a constant value, but according to the problem it should change. Please help

Answer (score 3):

use the dot operator **.** for element wise divsion.
Matlab assumes by default that you want to perform a matrix divsion if you use two vectors.

```
n = (t./x)
```

Comment: BTW `mrdivide`, the operation performed by `(t / x)`, performs "deconvolution" when both operands are vectors.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `n = (t./x);` rather than `n = (t/x);`

`t/x` is right-matrix division. Look at this:[mrdivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/mrdivide.html)

It should be element by element division, hence the dot operator needs to be used. Dot operator is used for element-wise division.

Instead of n = t./x, you can  rdivide(t,x) as well.